# Simple question about discrete metric and openness.

Tags: metric-spaces

You may think this is silly question, but I'm really confused.

In discrete metric, every singleton is an open set.

And, the proof goes like this

$\forall x \in X$, by choosing $\epsilon < 1$, $N_\epsilon(x) \subset ${$x$}

However, if discrete metric is defined in $X$,

How can we use the radius less than 1 when we only have 0 and 1?

Comment: Because the distance is a function defined to R+, not only the image

Comment: In fact, every subset of $X$ is an open set, since by the same argument you can find an open ball within the subset for every point in the subset. This is the "discrete topology".

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A metric on $X$ is a mapping $d:X \times X \to [0,\infty[$, so you can take $d = 1/2$ even if no pairs with distance $1/2$ exist.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take $\varepsilon<1$, you may take $\varepsilon=1$ also (can you see the reason?). But you need to know that the range of the metric (here $d$) is $\mathbb{R}^+$.